# Proving $f: \mathbb{R}^n \ni x\to \left\lVert x \right\rVert$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I had to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \ni x\to\left\lVert x \right\rVert$ $\in \mathbb{R}$  is continuous regarding maximum norm.

Is it correct to do the following, i.e. using triangle inequality?

$\left\lVert x \right\rVert$ = $\left\lVert x - y  + y\right\rVert$ $\leq $ $\left\lVert x - y \right\rVert$  $+ \left\lVert y \right\rVert$

$\left\lVert y \right\rVert$ = $\left\lVert y - x + x\right\rVert$ $\leq $ $\left\lVert y - x \right\rVert$  $+ \left\lVert x \right\rVert$

After rearranging I get

$|f(x) - f(y) |$ $\leq$  $\left\lVert x-y \right\rVert$

**which is why f is Lipschitz continuous**, and therefore continuous. (I think?)

Now there is $S := {x \in \mathbb{R}^n}$ : $\left\lVert x \right\rVert_\infty = 1$ which is the unit sphere regarding maximum norm. 
How can I now conclude from above, **that $f$ has a minimum** $A := f(x) > 0$ in a point $x$ on $S$?

And is it also possible to **conclude out of that, that therefore $\left\lVert x\right\rVert$ $\geq$ $A * \left\lVert x \right\rVert_\infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?**

Comment: Is $\Vert\Vert$  the standard Euclidean norm, or any norm or $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$. Basically the task was to prove step-by-step that all norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is possible by proving that every random norm  $\left\lVert * \right\rVert$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to the max norm  
 $\left\lVert * \right\rVert_\infty$

Comment: In that case, [this link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/equivalence-of-norms-in-a-finite-dimensional-linear-space) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not prove continuity of $f$ w.r.t. $\|x\|_{\infty}$ norm. Write any vector $x$ as $\sum x_ie_i$ where $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$ is the standard basis. Then $f(x) \leq \sum |x_i| |f(e_i)|\leq \|x\|_{\infty} \sum |f(e_i)|$ which proves that $f$ is continuous for the $\|x\|_{\infty}$ norm. Since $S$ is compact in $\|x\|_{\infty}$ norm it follows that $f$ has a minimum value $c$ on $S$. [Observe that $f$ does not vanish at any point of $S$]. Now you can verify that $f(x) \geq c \|x\|_{\infty}$ for all $x$ by considering $\frac x {\|x\|_{\infty}}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you evaluate on the last point? I don't understand how I can verify that $f(x) \geq c$ by considering what you have written...

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 Since $f$ is a norm, $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. Since it is continuous on the compact set $S$, its minimum value $c$ is positive.